# Firebase Push Notification how to set icon? Using Admin SDK in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Basically I want to set the icon on the push notification using Firebase. I am using their Firebase Admin .NET SDK. Which actually works just fine except for one minor detail, I cannot set the icon. Utilizing the class `FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Message` then specifying the attribute `Token` then specifying the `Notification` object (which has three attributes):

1. Body
2. ImageUrl
3. Title

After setting those the push notification works fine, but the `ImageUrl` is an actual image withing the message not the icon. I want to set the icon. After look through the docs I noticed that `Message` has an attribute called `Webpush` of type `WebpushConfig` which that has an attribute `Notification` of type `WebpushNotification` and boom! there they are, a bunch of settings like Tile, Body, Vibrate and others, but the one I really want is in there `Icon`. Unfortunately setting the attributes for `WebpushNotification` do not seem to do anything. Here is my code.

```
    public async Task Push(string token)
    {
        await messaging.SendAsync(new Message() { 
            Token = token,
            Notification = new Notification() {
              //Title = "This Title works",
              //Body = "This body works",
              //ImageUrl = "someUrlThatWorks"
            },
            Webpush = new WebpushConfig()
            {
                Notification = new WebpushNotification
                {
                    Title = "This title does not work",
                    Body = "This body does not work",
                    Icon = "thisIconDoesNotWork.png"
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Basically only the three attributes from `FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Notification work.`

But the attributes from `FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.WebpushNotification` I cannot get to work, I just want the `Icon` from there.

Here are the [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/dotnet/class/firebase-admin/messaging/message.html#class_firebase_admin_1_1_messaging_1_1_message)

Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

add the following to AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<!-- Set custom default icon. This is used when no icon is set for incoming notification messages. -->
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
<!-- Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming
     notification message. -->
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Comment: or  set the icon propert befire you send the notification: ```var msg = new Message()
            {
                Token = token,
               
                Notification = new Notification()
                {
                    Body = notificationBody,
                    Title = title,
                },
                
                Android = new AndroidConfig() { Notification = new AndroidNotification() { ClickAction = "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK", Icon= "ic_launcher" } },

            };```